# How to implement runas in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, security, embedded-linux

I’ve tried fork, setresgid, setresuid and execvpe — doesn’t work.

Specifically, no errors are returned anywhere, the child process starts OK, I have confirmed all 6 magic numbers returned by getresuid and getresgid match, yet the child process doesn’t have the required permissions.

The files in question are in the `/dev/input/` folder. Here’s the permissions:

```
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root           180 Sep 23 19:47 .
drwxr-xr-x   17 root     root          4120 Sep 23 19:47 ..
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root           160 Sep 23 19:47 by-path
crw-rw----    1 root     input      13,  64 Sep 23 19:47 event0
crw-rw----    1 root     input      13,  65 Sep 23 19:47 event1
crw-rw----    1 root     input      13,  66 Sep 23 19:47 event2
crw-rw----    1 root     input      13,  67 Sep 23 19:47 event3
crw-rw----    1 root     input      13,  68 Sep 23 19:47 event4
crw-rw----    1 root     input      13,  69 Sep 23 19:47 event5
```

The user is a member of the `input` group, that’s why under normal circumstances it can access these files. However, the process launched with fork/setresgid/setresuid/execvpe can’t access these files.

Here’s relevant lines from the strace log, the log was made with `-ff` option i.e. only includes a single process:

```
setresgid(10000, 10000, 10000)          = 0
setresuid(10000, 10000, 10000)          = 0
execve("/usr/local/bin/dotnet", ["/usr/local/bin/dotnet", "/home/user/launcher/Debug/Desktop.dll"], 0xffffea463f50 /* 1 var */) = 0
.. much later
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/input/event0", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
```

Comment: `/dev/input/event0` is normally the keyboard, and will be opened by the X server, as returned by `lsof`.

From the `openat` man page... `EPERM  The operation was prevented by a file seal; see fcntl(2).`

And if we look at `fcntl` man page, under `file sealing` we see... `For each seal that is set on a file, a specific set of operations will fail with EPERM on this file from now on.`

I assume this is what is happening.

If it is not X, then perhaps `lsof` will tell you what has already opened that file.

Comment: @Bib My target device does not have any keyboards, and I’m not running any display servers. When I start the same program normally from the shell, it works fine. The bug only happens when launching from another program which runs under root and calls these Linux APIs to switch to another user account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was indeed extra groups. Contrary to my expectation, `setresuid` does not refresh the list of additional groups.

To set them up, the launcher process first needs to call [getgrouplist](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getgrouplist.3.html) to query the list of additional groups for the target user, then after the fork call [setgroups](https://linux.die.net/man/2/setgroups) to apply these values.

The complete sequence of kernel calls to implement a Linux equivalent of [CreateProcessAsUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessasuserw) is following:

```
getgrouplist, fork, chdir, setresgid, setgroups, setresuid, execvpe
```

Note how `setresuid` needs to be the very last step before the `execvpe`. The reason for that, after that call the forked process no longer has permissions to modify these security-related things.

P.S. I wonder how many security bugs in Linux software were caused by the developers forgetting to update that list of extra groups when switching user accounts in their programs?